# Por que em algumas perguntas há um limite inferior maior que 50 nas recompensas?

Tags: debate, recompensa

Hoje eu "perdi" 50 pontos de reputação por ter atingido o cap, então pensei: "ei, é um bom dia pra oferecer uma recompensa: tem uma resposta que eu gostei muito, posso dar 50 pontos pra ela <del>e ainda não perco nada</del>!" (*Edit:* [perco sim...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69735/177950))

Só que quando fui colocar em prática, percebi que o mínimo que eu poderia oferecer era 100:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso acontece? É porque alguém já deu uma recompensa de 50 no passado? Ou é porque tem uma resposta minha também (é a resposta aceita, aliás, mas na minha opinião a outra é melhor). E seria prejudicial ao sistema se esse limite não fosse aumentado? (i.e. abriria margem pra abusos?)

P.S. Eu até acho que a resposta vale 100, e eu *vou* dar 100 pra ela. Mas hoje não! Já é tão difícil bater o cap, preciso aproveitar cada oportunidade possível... :P (*Edit:* me enganei de novo, [isso não importa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103/177950)... se eu ganhei pelo menos 200 ao longo do dia, pra efeito das medalhas é isso que conta, independentemente do quanto eu perdi. [Aguardando confirmação](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234921/177950) no caso de recompensas oferecidas)

Comment: `(Edit: aparentemente, perco sim...)` Você quer dizer que deu a recompensa e ainda assim seu limite se manteve o mesmo? Ou seja, desperdiçando upvotes?

Comment: @Math Sim. Se você observar [minha tabela de reputação de ontem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr?tab=reputation) (já é amanhã em UTC) verá que terminei com 180 - e tem vários upvotes que não geraram +10. Bom, valeu a tentativa, agora já sei como funciona... :P

Comment: Que droga! Odeio votos desperdiçados =/ Você chegou a receber algum voto a favor depois de dar a recompensa? Será que não daria certo? rs

Comment: @Math Não sei... estava com pressa, pois faltavam poucos minutos pra acabar o dia, então preferi escolher uma das minhas perguntas que não teve uma resposta satisfatória e pagar pra ver. Se fosse esperar uma confirmação antes de agir, perderia a oportunidade.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> É porque alguém já deu uma recompensa de 50 no passado?

Sim, ou porque tem uma resposta *sua* na pergunta. São duas regras:

- Se você já ofereceu uma recompensa antes na pergunta, a seguinte precisa ser ao menos duas vezes maior (até o limite de 500 pontos de reputação).
- Se existe uma resposta sua na pergunta, o limite mínimo de recompensa é mais alto (100, se não me engano).

O objetivo de ambas as regras é evitar abusos, pois as recompensas geram visibilidade para as perguntas e respostas, e portanto votos e reputação. É uma maneira de tentar prevenir que as recompensas saiam "de graça" ou deem "lucro".

Comment: Em outras palavras, ambos (i.e. se não fosse por um motivo, seria por outro), certo? E você sabe alguma coisa sobre a motivação por trás dessa funcionalidade? Tipo, se alguém ofereceu 50, depois outro ofereceu 100, o mínimo que o terceiro pode oferecer é 150?

Comment: É, você é sempre obrigado a subir a recompensa anterior, até o limite de 500. E quando tem resposta sua, o mínimo é maior para que as recompensas não sejam usadas simplesmente para atrair votos para a resposta existente.

Comment: Motivação: [**“Abusing” bounties for unlimited profit**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)