# Limite de reputações, como funciona?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Olhando nos guias do site, eu encontrei o seguinte trecho:

> Você pode ganhar no máximo 200 pontos de reputação por dia de qualquer combinação das atividades a seguir.
>
> Você ganha reputação quando:
>
> - a pergunta recebe votos a favor: +5
> - a resposta recebe votos a favor: +10
> - uma edição sugerida é aceita: +2 (até um total de +1000 por usuário)

Caso eu consiga esses 200 de reputação diários, os pontos que eu receberia naquele dia ainda, vindos desses atos citados, como ficam?

Comment: Muito boa pergunta. kkk. Uma vez, eu li isso aí e vi que o [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/) ganhava mais de 200 por dia.

Comment: Respondendo a dúvida de maneira curta, os pontos que você receberia você simplesmente deixa de receber. Não tenho certeza se os `+2` de edições sugeridas são contabilizados para esse limite. Os `+15` de aceitação, o bônus de associação e recompensas certamente não são.

Comment: Está [neste link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) @bfavaretto

Comment: [Meme Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/238766)

Comment: Eu tava vendo que Java é Skeet-completo, isso é verdade?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**O limite de reputação diária se aplica apenas para votos e edições sugeridas.**

Os votos que você recebe a favor (que valem +5 para perguntas e +10 para repostas) e edições sugeridas aprovadas (que valem +2) são contabilizadas até um limite de 200 pontos no dia, contado em UTC.

Se você receber um voto contra em alguma de suas publicações você perde 2 pontos, se você vota contra uma resposta você perde 1 ponto. Para esses dois casos, os pontos perdidos podem ser compensados pelos pontos extras que você recebeu de voto a favor e edições sugeridas.

Exemplo:
Você recebeu 25 votos a favor em respostas, o que totalizaria 250 pontos se não fosse o limite de 200. Nesse mesmo dia você recebe dois votos contras e perdeu 4 pontos, a reputação ganha nesse dia ainda assim será de 200, pois na verdade o total ganho foi de 246 e ele foi limitado em 200.

Entretanto, se você oferecer uma recompensa, seus pontos que excederam o limite não serão contabilizados

Exemplo:
Você recebeu 25 votos a favor em respostas e achou que seria uma boa ideia dar uma recompensa de 50 pontos para aproveitar os 50 pontos "desperdiçados", infelizmente, os 50 pontos sairão da sua reputação mesmo, e não dos 50 pontos que excederam o limite, então sua reputação naquele dia será de 150 pontos.

Fonte: [Por que em algumas perguntas há um limite inferior maior que 50 nas recompensas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1644/3117)

Pontos provenientes de aceitações (+15 se sua resposta foi aceita e +2 caso você tenha aceitado uma resposta), recompensas e o bônus de associação a um novo site da rede não contam no limite máximo de reputação diária.

Exemplo:
Se você atingiu a reputação máxima de 200 com os votos a favor, e em seguida ganhar uma recompensa de 50 e mais uma aceitação, sua reputação naquele dia será de 265 (200 em votos + 50 da recompensa + 15 da aceitação).

Os pontos provenientes de votos e edições sugeridas que excederem o limite de 200 não são concedidos no dia subsequente nem nunca mais, eles se vão para sempre :'(

Fonte: [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/229289)

Comment: nice work Math.